# ReactJS, Rails and Module.export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, reactjs, react-rails

Sorry for the slightly generic question. I am working on a Ruby on Rails and React.js based app using the `react_rails` gem and have reached a point where I need the ability to require modules across JS files.

I have tried every example I can find but seem to constantly have problems integrating things in a way that will allow `module.exports = 'XXXXX'`.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of a solid working example or can explain the best way to allow this using the `react_rails` gem?

Answer (score 0):

When we install react_rails gem, the file 'components.js' will be added to '/app/assets/javascript' with content:

```
//= require_tree ./components
```

That means every single javascript file in '/app/assets/javascript/components' folder will be loaded.

So when we define a new react class, just put the source file to '/components',

When you define a new react class, just put it in '/components/'. So don't worry about something like "module.exports = 'XXXXX'" anymore, Rails does it for us already. Otherwise, you may need to modify 'components.js'